# python .replace() regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do a grab everything after the `'</html>'` tag and delete it, but my code doesn't seem to be doing anything. Does `.replace()` not support regex?

```
z.write(article.replace('</html>.+', '</html>'))
```

Comment: Warning: parsing HTML with regular expressions [leads to madness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: I have a bunch of garbage after my closing html tag and I just want to remove it.

Comment: But what if your HTML has a quoted string, comment, JavaScript, or CDATA containing `</html>`?  Or what if the garbage at the end itself has a `</html>`?  Unless you can guarantee that none of those etc. can happen, you either need to fully parse the HTML or have some other way of knowing how much data you have (e.g. a `Content-Length:` HTTP header).

Comment: none of those things are a factor.

Answer (score 821, accepted):

No. Regular expressions in Python are handled by the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.

```
article = re.sub(r'(?is)</html>.+', '</html>', article)
```

In general:

```
str_output = re.sub(regex_search_term, regex_replacement, str_input)
```

Comment: How would I apply the re model to my 'article' variable?

Comment: I tried the following to no avail `z.write(re.sub(r'</html>.+', r'</html>', article))`

Comment: Is the tag not lowercase, or is it followed by a `'\n'`? You can make it case-insensitive (`(?i)` flag) and make `.` match newlines (`(?s)` flag) with `r'(?is)</html>.+'`.

Comment: Using flags would be more readable, i.e. adding flags=re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE as last argument iso the (?is) in the pattern.

Answer (score 110):

In order to replace text using regular expression use the [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

> sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])

It will replace non-everlaping instances of `pattern` by the text passed as `string`. If you need to analyze the match to extract information about specific group captures, for instance, you can pass a function to the `string` argument. [more info here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub).

**Examples**

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'a', 'b', 'banana')
'bbnbnb'

>>> re.sub(r'/\d+', '/{id}', '/andre/23/abobora/43435')
'/andre/{id}/abobora/{id}'
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `re` module for regexes, but regexes are probably overkill for what you want.  I might try something like

```
z.write(article[:article.index("</html>") + 7]
```

This is much cleaner, and should be much faster than a regex based solution.

Comment: Not so clean; you have to hard-code the length of "</html>".

Comment: @DanielGriscom : what about `len(str('</html>'))` ?

Comment: @OleAnders Better, but then you're duplicating that string, which opens another possibility for error.

Comment: @OleAnders ... and just realized; no need for the `str()`; just use `len('</html>')`

Comment: I was pretty much assuming this was a throwaway script - both the regex approach and the string search approach have all sorts of inputs they'll fail on. For anything in production, I would want to be doing some sort of more sophisticated parsing than either regex or simple string search can accomplish.

Answer (score 7):

For this particular case, if using `re` module is overkill, how about using `split` (or `rsplit`) method as

```
se='</html>'
z.write(article.split(se)[0]+se)
```

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

article='''<html>Larala
Ponta Monta 
</html>Kurimon
Waff Moff
'''
z=open('out.txt','w')

se='</html>'
z.write(article.split(se)[0]+se)
```

outputs `out.txt` as

```
<html>Larala
Ponta Monta 
</html>
```