# How to replace/remove regular expression in PySpark RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My sentence is say,
"I want to remove this string so bad."
I passed this text file as

```
text = sc.textFile(...)
```

and I want to filter out(i.e remove) the word "string"
I noticed that in python, there is a "re" package.
I tried doing

```
RDD.map(lambda x: x.replaceAll("<regular expression>", ""))
```

to filter out the "string" but seems like there is no such function in PySpark because it gave me an error..
How do I import "re" package? or is there any other function that I can use to remove/filter out certain string based on regular expression in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply import re package as shown below.

```
import re

text = sc.textFile(...)

out = re.sub("string", '', text)
print out
```

Comment: Looks like a working solution. Maybe you can add some comments on your answer to make it more personal and useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about specific provisioning for text in Spark, but a general way to do it (for any kind of var) would be to use the .map() method.

For example:

```
RDD.map(lambda s: s.replace("string",""))
```

Comment: can "string" inside .replace() be form of a regular expression?

Comment: According [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475885/python-replace-regex) replace cannot do it, but it can be done using re.

Answer (score 0):

To use re.sub on the contents of a textfile, use a lambda function for each line in the file:

`rdd_sub = rdd.map(lambda line: re.sub("<regexpattern>", "<newvalue>", line))`