# How to replace my customized characters with ' ' in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, character

I am trying to replace my own customized characters with ' '. Here is what I feel confused about:

If I just replace one character, it is OK:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'title':['a/b','a # b','a+b']})
a.loc[:,'title1']=a.loc[:,'title'].astype(str).str.replace('/',' ')
a
```

The result is:

```
   title title1
0    a/b    a b
1  a # b  a # b
2    a+b    a+b
```

If I use a short string which includes some characters, it is also OK:

```
b2='[?|:|-|\'|\\|/]'
a=pd.DataFrame({'title':['a/b','a # b','a+b']})
a.loc[:,'title1']=a.loc[:,'title'].astype(str).str.replace(b2,' ')
a
```

The result is:

```
   title title1
0    a/b    a b
1  a # b  a # b
2    a+b    a+b
```

But, when I try to use a long string to do this, nothing changes:

```
b1='[?|:|-|\'|\\|.|(|)|[|]|{|}|/]'
a=pd.DataFrame({'title':['a/b','a # b','a+b']})
a.loc[:,'title1']=a.loc[:,'title'].astype(str).str.replace(b1,' ')
a
```

The result is:

```
   title title1
0    a/b    a/b
1  a # b  a # b
2    a+b    a+b
```

You can see that in the first two examples, / is replaced with ' '. But in the last one, the replacement does not happen, which I do not know why? Is this because there is a limit for the string? Or, there is a better way that I do not know?

### Update

Thanks a lot @Oliver Hao. But what I what is to do this for one (or more) column in a data frame, then save the result back to the data frame as a new column. So when I try:

```
regex = r"[?:\-'\\\|.()\[\]{}/]"
a.loc[:,'title1']=re.sub(regex," ",a.loc[:,'title'],0,re.MULTILINE)
```

I have got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\fefechen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: I have not used python. You can see if it is a python version, because the test code I gave is 2.x, and you are using 3.x.

Comment: [Look at this .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475885/python-replace-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression might also work,

```
b1="[|,.:;+–_#&@!$%()[\]{}?'\"\/\\-]"
```

with less escapings.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to:`b1='[?:\-\'\\\|.()\[\]{}/]'`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zFoLqt/1)

Code:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"[?:\-'\\\|.()\[\]{}/]"

test_str = "'a/b','a # b','a+b'"

subst = " "

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. But I need to save the result back to the data frame as a new column. So it it different from your answer. And I do not know how to revise it. Could you please take a look at my edited question above? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers myself. The last one does not work because I should do this:

```
b1="[?|:|\-|\–|\'|\\|.|\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\}|/|#|+|,|;|_|\"|&|@|!|$|%|\|]"
```

put \ in front of some special characters.

Comment: The pipe between characters in a character class is useless.