# Python3: Replace splitted string

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my string:

```
VISA1240129006|36283354A|081016860665
```

I need to replace first string.

```
FIXED_REPLACED_STRING|36283354A|081016860665
```

I mean, I for example, I need to get next string:

Is there any elegant way to get it using python3?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this way:

```
>>> l = 'VISA1240129006|36283354A|081016860665'.split('|')
>>> l[0] = 'FIXED_REPLACED_STRING'
>>> l
['FIXED_REPLACED_STRING', '36283354A', '081016860665']
>>> '|'.join(l)
'FIXED_REPLACED_STRING|36283354A|081016860665'
```

Explanation: first, you split a string into a list. Then, you change what you need in the position(s) you want. Finally, you rebuild the string from such a modified list.

If you need a complete replacement of all the occurrences regardless of their position, check out also the other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.replace()` method:

```
l="VISA1240129006|36283354A|081016860665" 
l=l.replace("VISA1240129006","FIXED_REPLACED_STRING")
```

Comment: This is even better if you do not need to deal with "positional" replacement (ie. change exactly the _n-th_ string in pipe-separeted values). I mean, `replace` changes all the occurrences matching the filter. It depends on the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use re.sub() from regex library. See similar problem with yours. [replace string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475885/python-replace-regex/11475905)

My solution using regex is:

```
import re
l="VISA1240129006|36283354A|081016860665"
new_l = re.sub('^(\w+|)',r'FIXED_REPLACED_STRING',l)
```

It replaces first string before "|" character