# Use placeholder inside .replace()

Tags: python

With Python I need to replace a text but parts of the text is dynamical created. The start and finish of the string is always the same and unique.

Can I use placeholders inside `filedata.replace()` or is there a different method to solve that problem?

This did not work:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('<a href="/link/%s">Link</a>', '<a href="/link/replaced">Link</a>')
```

Comment: try to use regex

Comment: Read about [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: looks like you want to regex replace, or even parse html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475885/python-replace-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on the comments under my question:

```
import re
filedata = re.sub('<a href="/link/(.*?)">Link</a>', '<a href="/link/replaced">Link</a>', filedata)
```

Read about [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).